# Skydrive app sync files to local computer

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

How can I get the SkyDrive app in Windows 8 to download all my files to a folder on my machine and keep them synced? For now, I can view the files but can't sync them to a folder like the application in Windows 7 did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Modern UI SkyDrive app cannot do this, however you can still download the desktop application from [here](https://apps.live.com/skydrive) to accomplish this the same way as in Windows 7.

Comment: Wouldn't it perhaps be better to say "The Metro SkyDrive app cannot do this *yet*"?

Comment: @Karan Possibly, however that sounds like I know this feature is coming, which I certainly don't...unless you know of a source that confirms that? I'll be happy to update if so!

Comment: You're right, while it does seem likely to me that the feature will be added in future (it's early days yet after all and the OS hasn't yet reached GA), I don't know for sure either.